# time zone not changing while storing data in mysql,codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, timezone

I am working on a website that involves storing and retrieving query.Since I am working on a shared server,I cant change the server timezone.So I coded this in constructors of both storing and displaying

```
public function __construct( )
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db->query("SET SESSION time_zone = '+05:30'");


}
```

This worked for displaying but not storing.As in values in database are according to some other timezone but not so while they are displayed on the website.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` add this before your insert query. Better add this at the beginning of main index.php so that you don't need write before every query.

Answer (score 0):

You can set time zone with php code.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
```

[here](http://www.date-default-timezone-set.com/) you can find all the list

You need to do it Before inserting values at database and before displaying data.
But I personally added that code at the beginning of codeigniter main `index.php` file. So that I don't need write it every time.
Hope It will help you.

Comment: Thanks but that code already exists in my index.php,and doesnt make a difference to my database entries.

Comment: It should work.try to write this code in a php file and run `$time=time();
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
echo date("Y-n-j G:i:s",$time)."<br>";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
echo date("Y-n-j G:i:s",$time);
` if you see there is 30min difference both two line means its working.

Comment: my php timezone works fine..but the thing is  there are columns in the table which have current timestammp as default value..i'm not sending any values for such attributes.

Comment: why don't you send it from your php code which will solve your problem.

Comment: I had thought of that earlier but wanted to still figure out why mysql query wasnt working..will do now as u said ...thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In upcoming version of CodeIgniter, we will introduce with a awesome configuration option for setting timezone. Currently we can only set "local" or "gmt" at "time_reference" option. But in upcoming version we will be able to use "time_reference" like "Asia/Dhaka" or "Australia/Sydney". That means we will be able use all the timezones supported by PHP. But what we need to do if we want to use this feature in older version of CodeIgniter. Surely, there are couple of ways. But today I want to share the simple tricks to use timezones in CodeIgniter older version (< 3.0-dev version).

To do that we need to follow the following step:

=> Need to extend the date helper with the following function.

```
if ( ! function_exists('now'))
{
    /**
     * Get "now" time
     *
     * Returns time() based on the timezone parameter or on the
     * "time_reference" setting
     *
     * @param   string
     * @return  int
     */
    function now($timezone = NULL)
    {
        if (empty($timezone))
        {
            $timezone = config_item('time_reference');
        }
        if ($timezone === 'local' OR $timezone === date_default_timezone_get())
        {
            return time();
        }
        $datetime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
        sscanf($datetime->format('j-n-Y G:i:s'), '%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d', $day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute, $second);
        return mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
    }
}
```

=> Now in config.php at "time_reference" option we can use timezones like:

`$config['time_reference'] = 'Asia/Dhaka';`

To know more: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/109912/109912-5953416141937405955